# add month to a date moment js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to add no of months to a given date using js. fd_start_date has the start date, but moment.js returns "Invalid Date". I am using date picker to select date in format YYYY-MM-DD.

```
$('#fd_start_date').click(function () {
            var start_date=$("#fd_start_date").val();
            var no_of_months=$("#fd_duration").val();
            var currentDate = moment(start_date);
            var future_date = moment(currentDate).add(no_of_months, 'months');
            console.log(future_date);

        });
```

Comment: What's the value of no_of_months before you define future_date?

Comment: it could be a value, 1 to 36 months. if start date is today, the future date shall be 2018-11-04 if the no of months is 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works for me if I change to on input and have a value in the month field

```js
$('#fd_start_date, #fd_duration').on("input",function() {
  var start_date = $("#fd_start_date").val();
  if (start_date) {
    var no_of_months = $("#fd_duration").val();
    var currentDate = moment(start_date);
    var future_date = moment(currentDate).add(no_of_months, 'months');
    console.log(future_date);
  }  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>

<input type="date" id="fd_start_date" /><input type="number" id="fd_duration" value="1" />
```

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this in the following way:

```js
// Getting the current moment
const currentTime = moment()

// Adding a month to it
const futureMonth = currentTime.add(1, 'M');

console.log(futureMonth)
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/moment/moment/2.2.1/min/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Just change the code to add a `.format()`. `const futureMonth = currentTime.add(1, 'M').format('YYYY-MM-DD');`

Comment: And just a note of personal preference, but any time I use date math (like in `add()`) then I prefer to be explicit in the unit I'm mathing: (`add(1, 'month')` or `add(42,'year')`)

Comment: And last note, for date masking, case does matter here. `YYYY-MM-DD` is much different than `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Answer (score 0):

**I am using this in my project and this logic is working fine for me.**
$scope.o.DateOfBirth = "31/03/2021";
var currentDate =moment($scope.o.DateOfBirth, 'DD/MM/YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
var futureMonth = moment(currentDate ).add(24, 'month').format("YYYY-MM-DD");

console.log(currentDate.format('DD-MM-YYYY'));
console.log(futureMonth.format('DD-MM-YYYY'));

****output : "2023-03-31"****